# Hugo mod init command does not create mod file

Tags: go, module, hugo

I just installed hugo v0.62.2/extended via snap on Ubuntu 18.04. I have Go 1.13.5 installed. In my project directory when I run:

```
hugo mod init
```

no go.mod file is produced. Output of verbose command is as follows:

> INFO 2020/01/18 20:41:23 No translation bundle found for default language "en" 
>   INFO 2020/01/18 20:41:23 Translation func for language en not found, use default. 
>   INFO 2020/01/18 20:41:23 i18n not initialized; if you need string translations, check that you have a bundle in /i18n that matches the site language or the default language. 
>   INFO 2020/01/18 20:41:23 Using config file:

How to I generate the go.mod file or find out why it is not being generated?

Comment: Have you tried adding the module path? `hugo mod init path/to/mod`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue when installing hugo via the Software Centre. This is how I had installed it. I uninstalled it and then installed the linux [binary release](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases) in my /usr/local/bin folder and now hugo mod init does indeed produce the go.mod file

Answer (score 0):

[`hugo mod init`](https://gohugo.io/commands/hugo_mod_init/) is supposed to guess a module path, but it is easier if you pass it explicitly.

See "[Hugo modules](https://craftsmandigital.net/blog/hugo-modules/)" from by [Jon Arne Viksås](https://craftsmandigital.net/authors/craftsmandigital)

> ```
> hugo mod init test-dummy
> ```
>
> YES IT WAS `test-dummy`.
>   I think it’s more appropriate to name the module as your Hugo site name.
>
> The command could output something like this:
>
> go: creating new go.mod: module test-dummy
>       information: a new file go.mod was created

I don't see any recent changes in [`commands/mod.go`](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/blame/ea9261e856c13c1d4ae05fcca08766d410b4b65c/commands/mod.go).

Comment: I've tried with a module path, but it still doesn't output anything. If I run go mod init I get a go.mod file ok, but not with hugo mod init